# Regex to parse megavideo URL

Tags: php, regex, string-parsing

I'm trying to write a regex to parse a this url for a php script:

http://www.megavideo.com/v/B4PZHP0Nb2e8a877f8378e778446318596415780

to get this: B4PZHP0N

Can someone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use the substring functions of your language.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're in PHP, just use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php):

```
$mega = 'http://www.megavideo.com/v/B4PZHP0Nb2e8a877f8378e778446318596415780';
$want = substr(parse_url($mega, PHP_URL_PATH), 3, 8);
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/f3viH

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
/^http:\/\/www\.megavideo\.com\/v\/(.{8}).*$/
```

(The error has been corrected)

Also see my [ideone](http://ideone.com/ePWIe) or my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nWmWA/).

Answer (score 0):

`/([^:.\/]+)[a-f0-9]{32}/`

So if it matches, B4PZHP0N is in capture buffer 1, ie: $1

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar but a bit more generic.
so the id can come either after /v/, ?v= or &v=

```
$url = 'http://www.megavideo.com/v/B4PZHP0Nb2e8a877f8378e778446318596415780';
foreach (array('/v/', '?v=', '&v=') as $k)
{
    $pos = strpos($url, $k);
    if ($pos>0)
    {
        $pos += strlen($k);
        break;
    }   
}   
if (!$pos)
    die("not found");
$id = substr($url, $pos, 8);
die($id);
```